# How to Call a View Helper Method in JavaScript using Rails 3.1

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, view-helpers

I'm working on a simple app that needs to render a time. But the time must be formatted the way time_ago_in_words helper does. I'm getting the time data from a JSON object. Is it possible to trigger a view helper (time_ago_in_words) inside a JavaScript file? I'm using Rails 3.1

Thanks.

Comment: How is the JSON object created? If it's created via a ruby object you could override ```as_json``` to format it the way you want.

Comment: From the controller, I used the render :json => { :values => myarrayofobjects }.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it from inside a javascript function.

Ideally you would want a JSON equivalent to XML Builder where you could call the view helper methods from inside a .builder partial.
This gem provides similar functionality https://github.com/lassebunk/api_builder.

Comment: Thanks simianarmy. What I did was use JS library that mimic the time_ago_in_words.