# How do I call a method in application helper from a assets/javascript/partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to Ruby on Rails development.

I have a function in application_helper.rb

```
def fb_like_button(url)
    content_tag(:iframe,nil, src: "//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=#{url}width=83&layout=button_count&action=like&show_faces=true&share=false&height=21&appId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
 end
```

This function is working in views, I am seeing facebook like button in webpage

But its not working in partials.

> app/assets/javascript/partials

this is my partials index.html.slim

```
.row
   | {{ fb_like_button("https://www.facebook.com/page/?fref=ts") }}
```

From the above code its running without any error but I didn't see facebook like button in the webpage.

Please Advice me on this issue

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Structure or Rails convention you make some wrongs things likes.

1 . partial names in Rails as _partailaneme.html.erb or .slim, started with _ symbol.

2 . please add your (View or html) partial or template in View folder specific controller view folder.

please go throw link and please learn Ruby on Rails

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/index.html

Comment: Its in angularjs. that partials path is app/assets/javascript/partial

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572576/how-to-call-a-view-helper-method-in-javascript-using-rails-3-1

Comment: one way is create the , html in anguler pass the particulate rails data or attributes as format of json or hash .